# How to use nvdia graphic card instead of Intel while using tensorflow-gpu?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, intel, nvidia

my laptop has two different graphic cards; one of them is Intel other one is Nvdia GeForce GTX 1060 with Max-Q Design.

I want to train my model using Nvidia GPU however while i start the code i see that Intel GPU is using instead of Nvidia. (By checking resource monitor)

How can i push my code to evaluate operations on Nvidia?

Thanks in advance.

Code output is on below;

```
2019-05-16 22:00:08.022034: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX AVX2
    2019-05-16 22:00:09.109537: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1433] Found device 0 with properties:
    name: GeForce GTX 1060 with Max-Q Design major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.3415
    pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0
    totalMemory: 6.00GiB freeMemory: 4.97GiB
    2019-05-16 22:00:09.115599: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1512] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
    2019-05-16 22:00:09.732522: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:984] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
    2019-05-16 22:00:09.735119: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:990]      0
    2019-05-16 22:00:09.736802: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1003] 0:   N
    2019-05-16 22:00:09.738843: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1115] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 4714 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1060 with Max-Q Design, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
    WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\math_ops.py:3066: to_int32 (from tensorflow.python.ops.math_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
    Instructions for updating:
    Use tf.cast instead.
    2019-05-16 22:00:10.947582: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1512] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
    2019-05-16 22:00:10.950781: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:984] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
    2019-05-16 22:00:10.953529: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:990]      0
    2019-05-16 22:00:10.955159: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1003] 0:   N
    2019-05-16 22:00:10.957471: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1115] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 4714 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1060 with Max-Q Design, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
    2019-05-16 22:00:11.016401: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1512] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
    2019-05-16 22:00:11.020139: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:984] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
    2019-05-16 22:00:11.023906: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:990]      0
    2019-05-16 22:00:11.026780: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1003] 0:   N
    2019-05-16 22:00:11.030436: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1115] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 4714 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1060 with Max-Q Design, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
    WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\saver.py:1266: checkpoint_exists (from tensorflow.python.training.checkpoint_management) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
    Instructions for updating:
    Use standard file APIs to check for files with this prefix.
    2019-05-16 22:00:12.013549: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1512] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
    2019-05-16 22:00:12.016873: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:984] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
    2019-05-16 22:00:12.021027: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:990]      0
    2019-05-16 22:00:12.023952: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1003] 0:   N
    2019-05-16 22:00:12.026487: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1115] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 4714 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1060 with Max-Q Design, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
    Processing...
    row 0 of 1696
    2019-05-16 22:00:12.326057: I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:152] successfully opened CUDA library cublas64_90.dll locally
```

Comment: No, tensorflow does not support Intel GPUs, your code is running in the GTX 1060 GPU.

Comment: It's on Nvidia. Cuda does not work on Intel. Also to make sure, you can use`nvidia-smi` to see how much Nvidia GPU is using when you run your code.

Comment: Thanks for clear answers, they helped lot.